# using j2ee to load BLOB always gets null for BLOB attribute of entity bean

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, blob

I want to load a BLOB from database using EJB.

Problem: The BLOB attribute is alsways null.

The blob attribute looks like this in the bean:

```
@Column(name = "REPORT_PARAMETER", length = 50000) // tried already: removing "length"
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) // tried already: uncomment, changing to "LAZY"
private byte[] reportParameters;
```

I load the bean like this:

```
TestCacheDataBE data= (TestCacheDataBE) em.find(TestCacheDataBE.class, cacheId);
```

The loading works, I can read all the other attributes fine. Only the BLOB attribute is always null.

There is data in the database. A SELECT shows me the BLOB column is not null.

```
select dbms_lob.getlength(report_parameter)
from T_REPORT_CACHE;
```

The above statement shows me, there is data in the BLOB column.

The data is saved using also the bean and entitymanager like this:

```
em.persist(data);
```

But the saving works fine!

So the only problem is loading the BLOB data from the database into the bean. Saving works, and loading all the other data works also.

I use weblogic 10, Java 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we solved the problem. I'll document the solution here for others, because apparently, no one knew the answer.

It was a driver problem. We used the Weblogic driver:

```
<jdbc-driver-params>
 <url>jdbc:bea:oracle://domain:1541</url>
 <driver-name>weblogic.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver</driver-name>
```

It works with Oracle driver:

```
<jdbc-driver-params>
 <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1542:abcd</url>
 <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-name>
```

Fun fact: 
It used to work with the Weblogic driver (on Windows 7). But something changed and it did not work anymore (maybe a Windows update or an Oracle-database update changed something). Now it only works with the Oracle-driver. We deploy on a Linux server, there it still works with the Weblogic driver.